# The relative difference goes towards negative infinity when it's supposed to go towards 0

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have written the following code to plot the velicity-courses of two different models (blue and green line) and the relative difference between them (orange line):

```
%% ----- Absolulte Carvelocity v[km/h] in carfixed Coordinate system ----
%  Define Plotproperties
figure('Position', [100, 100, 1024, 768]);
hold on; grid on;
title('Absolute Velocity');
xlabel('time t[s]');
ylabel('absolute velocity v[km/h]');
xlim([t_start t_end]);

% Calculate the difference between the models
t = erg_sl.Vehicle.v_ms.Time;
v_ms = reshape(erg_sl.Vehicle.v_ms.Data,1,[],1);
diff=zeros(1,size_cmtime(2));
for ctr=1:size_cmtime(2)
    diff(1,ctr)=-(erg_cm.Car_v.data(ctr)*3.6-v_ms(1,round(ctr*fac))*3.6)/abs(erg_cm.Car_v.data(ctr)*3.6)*100;
end

% From Carmaker
line(erg_cm.Time.data,erg_cm.Car_v.data .* 3.6,'Color','b','LineWidth',2)

% From Simulink
line(erg_sl.Vehicle.v_ms.Time,erg_sl.Vehicle.v_ms.Data .* 3.6,'Color',[0,0.6,0.5],'LineWidth',2)

% Legend
legend('Carmaker','Simulink');

% Change axes
ax1 = gca;
%ax1.XLim = [0 20];
%ax1.YLim = [-15 15];
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'YAxisLocation','right', 'Color','none','YColor',[255,127,80]/256);
ax2.YLim = [-30 30];
ax2.YLabel.String = 'Relative difference [%]';
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x');

% Plot the difference
line(erg_cm.Time.data,diff,'Parent',ax2,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[255,127,80]/256)

% legend
legend('Relative Abweichung','Location','South')

%  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actually it works quite fine and i get this plot:
[image: Generated Plot]

Now the problem is, that in the beginning the difference is actually almost zero, but the orange line (which is the relative difference) goes towards negative infinity. You can even see that from `t=0` to `t~75` the green line is even above the blue one and so the orange one is supposed to be above 0. So what is wrong about the code, so this happens?

EDIT: Here's another plot of the same script which looks a lot more like what I expected. The orange line heads towards `-inf`, too, but just for Divisors that are smaller than one which is logical to me:
[image: Plot that I expect]

Comment: Hum, it seems that since both blue and green are asymptotically becoming constant, so is orange; around a value of -12 judging your graph.

Comment: The curves (blue and green) are the velocitys of a car driving at a constant wheeltorque calculated by different models. So yes, all lines are supposed to become constant asymptotically, but the orange is supposed to start from zero and tend towards about -12 and not to start from `-inf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *relative* difference `(x-y)./x` can tend to `inf` or `-inf` even if the *absolute* difference `x-y` tends to `0`.

Consider for example:

```
t = logspace(0,-5,8);        %// tends to zero
x = t;                       %// tends to zero
y = sqrt(t);                 %// tends to zero, but more slowly than x
absDiff = x-y;               %// tends to zero
relDiff = (x-y)./x           %// tends to -inf
```

This gives

```
t =
    1.0000    0.1931    0.0373    0.0072    0.0014    0.0003    0.0001    0.0000

absDiff =
         0   -0.2463   -0.1558   -0.0776   -0.0359   -0.0161   -0.0071   -0.0032

relDiff =
         0   -1.2758   -4.1795  -10.7877  -25.8270  -60.0540 -137.9495 -315.2278
```

Comment: yes sure it can tend towards `inf` and `-inf`, but only if x (the divisor) tends to `0` or at least is smaller than `1`. In my plot you can see, that the relative difference tends to `-inf` even though, the divisor is still taller then `50`. So either I didn't get you right, or this is not the actual problem.

Comment: i've added another plot which looks a lot more like what i expected.